# modal does not open because of flat-ui

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, flatui

I want to use flat-ui from designmodo free version 2.2.2. But I found that documents that related to include Flat-UI into rails are out of date. So I download the package and include it by

```
<link href="/Flat-UI-2.2.2/dist/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Flat-UI-2.2.2/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
```

including these codes. 

So it works fine in my project except my modal. My modal turns on, but turns off right away. So I'm searching about this problem, and found that this problem is related to include bootstrap twice(or maybe Flat-ui twice).

So I include that code just in my application.html.erb once or just include that code page by page, But can't solve it.

Can anybody help me?
My project code is on
https://ide.c9.io/hcn1519/modalra#openfile-README.md

My problem demo is on http://modalra-hcn1519-1.c9.io/ here.

Comment: remove `<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-bcfe54f3132bf16a8c5ce4289e47eba488f6522a08f49f378a037061c6c7aa4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason modal open and instantly closed because 2 JS libraries handling the modal open request,

[Fiddle With Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/48hkxygk/)

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-bcfe54f3132bf16a8c5ce4289e47eba488f6522a08f49f378a037061c6c7aa4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="/Flat-UI-2.2.2/dist/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So remove one and will fix the issue. I suggest remove

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-bcfe54f3132bf16a8c5ce4289e47eba488f6522a08f49f378a037061c6c7aa4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

[Working Modal Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48hkxygk/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot find `<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-bcfe54f3132bf16a8c5ce4289e47eba488f6522a08f49f378a037061c6c7aa4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>` from asset pipeline.

Comment: Oh man.. or woman.. I erased `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` from  `/asset/javascripts/application.js` and it works. Maybe `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` included what you said. Thank you~

Comment: Oh I'm man and was unable to access this https://ide.c9.io/hcn1519/modalra#openfile-README.md so I just checked this http://modalra-hcn1519-1.c9.io/ and if you take view source of page you will see `/assets/bootstrap/modal` at line 21

Comment: oh, I think members of Cloud9(my IDE) only can access my project. I included bootstrap via `bootstrap-sass` gem, actually from `https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise` this source. So I put some code that you cannot see if you cannot access my project source directly. Anyway, it works well! Thank you and enjoy your work!